# Access request param in node with express

Tags: node.js, express

I have some routes in node express as below.

I need to access the request params out of router functions(get, post ...) in order to set a const with a folder account of a user.
This is the line in the snippet code:

```
const uploadPath = path.join(__dirname, "../..", `public/${req.data.account_id}/uploads/clientes`);
```

Is it possible?

```
//app.js
....
app.use('products',productRoutes)

//productRoutes
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const path = require("path");
//here I need access req params
const uploadPath = path.join(__dirname, "../..", `public/${req.data.account_id}/uploads/clientes`);

router.get('/list',(req,res)=>{
  console.log(uploadPath);
  ....
  ....
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of **uploadPath**? Do you want to use it in the response?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that accepts a parameter for the request object, then builds and returns your path:

```
app.use('products',productRoutes)

//productRoutes
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const path = require("path");
//here I need access req params


function createPath(reqObj) {
   return path.join(__dirname, "../..", `public/${reqObj.data.account_id}/uploads/clientes`);
}
router.get('/list',(req,res)=>{
  const neededPath = createPath(req);
  console.log(neededPath);
  ....
  ....
}
```

Comment: @LuizAlves Did you have any luck with this??